# SwiftUI view exceeds explicitly set frame

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view where I explicitly set the frame. But still, it looks like the view height depends on the content height and can exceed the frame. Happens basically because the sub-title on the 2nd view uses 2 lines.

View itself:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text(viewModel.badge)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .padding([.bottom, .top], 3).padding([.leading, .trailing], 7)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 1))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
                HStack {
                    Text(viewModel.title)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            Image(viewModel.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 88, height: 88)
        }.padding(.bottom, 10)
        HStack {
            Text(viewModel.subtitle)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .padding(15)
    .background(ThemeManager.current.primaryCardBackgroundColor.color)
    .cornerRadius(9)
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
            .stroke(ThemeManager.current.primaryCardBackgroundColor.color, lineWidth: 0))
}
```

`ScrollView` with views

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        HStack(spacing: 16) {
            Banner(title: "Bla bla bla bla ",
                   text: "Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla .",
                   badge: "BEST",
                   image: Image("xxx"))
                .frame(width: 335, height: 180)
            Banner(title: "Bla bla bla bla ",
                   text: "Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla ",
                   badge: "Bla",
                   image: Image("banner-card"))
                .frame(width: 335, height: 180)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 180)
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I make the view not to exceed the given frame?

Comment: did you try maxHeight parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the screen size is only around `390-410` for the latest iPhones, but each **Banner** view you have here has a **width** of **335** already which means you used more screen than you have. Since you are using `HStack`, this problem is expected.

3 solutions here.

1. If you want a `carousel view` effect, just add a modifier to your ScrollView like this `ScrollView(.horizontal)`, then you will be able to scroll and see all banners horizontally. This allows you to keep all your original banners without modifying anything.
2. Another solution here is to reframe your Banner size to something under the maximum screen size. something like this:

   ```
   Banner()
      .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.45, height: 180)
   Banner()
      .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.45, height: 180)
   //this fixed the problem because you are using only 90% screen size, so both banners will be displayed within the screen.
   ```

[image]

3. If having the width size of `335` for your banners is a must, then you can use `VStack` instead of `HStack`. Also, when using VStack don’t forget to give your stack a new frame size that can fit two banners like the below code.

   ```
   ScrollView {
           VStack { //here
               Banner()
                   .frame(width: 335, height: 180)
               Banner()
                   .frame(width: 335, height: 180)
           }
           .padding()
           .frame(height: 360) //here
       }
   ```

[image]

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing paddings/spacing. Looks like swiftui ignores the height if the size of the context + paddings/spacings all together is bigger. Looks like there is no other option rather than making a few things a bit smaller. And to make the view stretch if the accumulated size is smaller I just used Spacer()

Comment: I think you are confused here. Your problem here is "exceed the max width", but you keep mentioning about height in your question and comment.

Comment: No, I guess you misunderstood what I wanted to achieve. On the screenshot, you can see 2 lines. One is bigger than the other one. Meaning 1 height is bigger than the other one. I have them already in a ScrollView (2nd code snippet). No issue with width, only with height.

Comment: @Artiom Try this new solution, you want your frame to remains fixed without getting affected by the growth of contents inside right? Then this should be prevented by setting limit to the content which likely to grow too much.  use `.lineLimit(1)` to all your Banner(text, title...etc), so Text() will not grow exceed one line to maintain your Rectangle() frame. eg: Text("Title Here).lineLimit(1). This is the only solution, otherwise your text can grow to any line.

Comment: This can work, thanks, but to fit the whole text in 1 line I also need minimumScaleFactor to set.